# Cannot preprocess data in Binary Text Classification with Naive Bayes and multiple features

Tags: dataframe, scikit-learn, naivebayes, countvectorizer

I have a binary Classification Problem where I want to classify my data into two groups: carcompany and noncarcompany. I crawled websites and extracted the follwoing features (simplified):

1. domain: The website I crawled
2. asn: The Autonomous systems number of the server
3. robots: If the website had the robots.txt activated
4. email: the amil address of the website owner
5. diff_days_stand: the days the website is online
6. html_title: the parsed html title of the website

I tried out a baseline model where X is "html_title" and y is "carcompany"  and achieved an Accuracy of 0.95, so quite well. I opted for a Complementary NB instead of a Multinomial because I know the final data for classification will be imbalanced. I wanted to add some more features (columns) to the prediction even though I know that the assumption of conditional independence might be violated.

However I cannot manage the preprocessing (including the Dataframe). After reading up on NB again I have doubts now, so my questions are:

1. Can Naive Bayes be used with Multiple features (columns)?
2. Can NaiveBayes be used for text classification with multiple classes of features (String, Integer, Boolean)? What if I convert them all to strings?
3. Is my code wrong and where?

Thanks in advance :)

#### Import Packages

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import ComplementNB
```

#### Create Data

```
dummy = {"domain":["a.de","b.de","c.de","d.de","e.de","f.de","g.de","h.de","i.de","j.de","k.de","l.de","m.de","n.de","o.de","p.de","q.de","r.de","s.de","t.de","u.de","v.de","w.de","x.de","y.de","z.de","aa.de","bb.de","cc.de"],
"asn":["123","789","491","238","148","369","123","458","231","549","894","153","654","658","987","369","258","147","852","963","741","652","365","547","785","985","589","632","456"],
"robots":["True","Test","False","True","False","False","False","False","True","False","False","True","False","True","True","Test","False","True","True","True","False","True","True","False","False","True","False","False","False"],
"email":["@a.de","@b.de","@c.de","@d.de","@e.de","@f.de","@g.de","@h.de","@i.de","@j.de","@k.de","@l.de","@m.de","@n.de","@o.de","@p.de","@q.de","@r.de","@s.de","@t.de","@u.de","@v.de","@w.de","@x.de","@y.de","@z.de","@aa.de","@bb.de","@cc.de"],
"diff_days_stand":["0.9","0.8","0.7","0.6","0.5","0.4","0.3","0.2","0.1","0.9","0.8","0.7","0.6","0.5","0.9","0.8","0.7","0.6","0.5","0.4","0.3","0.2","0.1","0.9","0.8","0.7","0.6","0.5","0.1"],
"html_title":["audi bmw mercedes", "audi bmw mercedes", "audi bmw mercedes", "audi bmw mercedes", "audi bmw mercedes", "audi bmw mercedes", "audi bmw mercedes", "audi bmw mercedes", "audi bmw mercedes", "audi bmw mercedes", "apple dell acer", "apple dell acer", "apple dell acer", "apple dell acer", "apple dell acer", "apple dell acer", "apple dell acer", "apple dell acer", "apple dell acer", "apple dell acer", "audi bmw mercedes", "apple dell acer", "audi bmw mercedes", "apple dell acer", "audi bmw mercedes", "apple dell acer", "audi bmw mercedes", "apple dell acer", "audi bmw mercedes"]}
dummy = pd.DataFrame(dummy)
stopwords = ['a','ab','aber','ach','acht']
```

#### Convert Data to strings (not surre if it is correct to convert int and booleans to strings)

```
list1 = ['domain', 'asn', 'robots', 'email', 'diff_days_stand', 'html_title'] 
for i in list1:
    dummy[i] = dummy[i].astype(str)
```

#### Prepare Trainingsdata

```
train_t = dummy.loc[0:9,("domain", "asn", "robots", "email", "diff_days_stand", "html_title")].copy().reset_index()
train_f = dummy.loc[10:19,("domain", "asn", "robots", "email", "diff_days_stand", "html_title")].copy().reset_index()
rest    = dummy.loc[20:30, ("domain", "asn", "robots", "email", "diff_days_stand", "html_title")].copy().reset_index()

train_t["carcompany"] = 1
train_f["carcompany"] = 0
train_tot = train_f.append(train_t)
train_tot = train_tot.drop(labels="index", axis=1)

y = train_tot["carcompany"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_tot, y , test_size=0.25, random_state=53)
```

#### This is where something is wrong

```
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords)
X_train_transformed =  cv.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_transformed = cv.transform(X_test)
```

> X_train is a sparse matrix of 4x4. It should be much bigger with additional features

```
cb = ComplementNB(alpha=1.0, fit_prior=True, class_prior=None, norm=False)
cb.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train, sample_weight=None)

pred = cb.predict(X_test_transformed)
score = cb.score(X_test_transformed, y_test)
```

#### Depending on what I tried I also got these messages:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7, 15]
>
> NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 0):

you need to vectorize your textual data column (which i think is html_title) rather whole X_train

```
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords)
X_train_transformed =  cv.fit_transform(X_train['html_title'])

textual_feature =  pd.DataFrame(X_train_transformed.todense(), columns =cv.get_feature_names())
```

now add others feature to this dataframe  that you think will improve your model predicting power